# Setting up Ruhoh. ERROR: repository not found

Tags: git, github, repository

Instructions from [ruhoh.com](http://ruhoh.com/) state to setup a repository `USERNAME.ruhoh.com`, which has been done. https://github.com/NredYssuts/nredyssuts.ruhoh.com also asks to add a web hook, which has also been done.

Then it gives the following instructions to execute:

```
    $ git clone git://github.com/ruhoh/blog.git USERNAME.ruhoh.com
    $ cd USERNAME.ruhoh.com
    $ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USERNAME/USERNAME.ruhoh.com.git
    $ git push origin master
```

I am able to execute the first three lines and then on the fourth I am asked to enter my passphrase for `/home/nredyssuts/.ssh/id_rsa`

I do that correctly and then bam!

```
    ERROR: Repository not found.
    fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I'm not sure why this is happening at all. This is a public repository.

Comment: turns out it was a case sensitive issue. git@github.com:NredYssuts was the fix. didn't realise my username had capitals....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! you should add this comment into an self-answer to your question, and later accept it so that it's clearer for others that your problem has been resolved